# Complicated Python OCR - Is it possible?

Tags: python, excel, ocr

My company works with architectural plans where each room is given a room name and number. The room name is always bolded and underlined, and the room number is always inside a rectangle beneath the room name (for confidentiality reasons, I can't post pictures). The plans have a little bit of noise, and there are occasionally thin lines through the room name/number text. On a single pdf page there can be many rooms, each with a room name/number in a different position within its room. I'd like to send all the room names and numbers to an Excel spreadsheet. Is this doable with a free OCR library?

I know literally nothing about OCR with Python, so just wondering before I spend time figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

If just a simple OCR library, no.
You have to use algorithms/models to detect numbers in your PDF page first, then a simple OCR library can help you to read the number in your case.